# Update Listview after updating CSV file in Android

Tags: java, android, csv, android-listview

My Android App is currently reading the data from the CSV file and displaying it in the `ListView`,  however, once I add another row to my CSV file, I want the app to update the newly added values on click of a refresh button.  How to do that?   Any help would be appreciated

Below is the code

**MainActivity Class**

````
```public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listView;
    private ItemArrayAdapter itemArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //init();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_View);
        itemArrayAdapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_premier_rostatus);

        Parcelable state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();
        listView.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);
        listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.stats);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        List<String[]> scoreList = csvFile.read();

        for (String[] scoreData : scoreList) {
            itemArrayAdapter.add(scoreData);
        }

    }
}```
````

**ItemArrayAdapter Class**

````
    private List<String[]> scoreList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    static class ItemViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView score;
    }

    public ItemArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(String[] object) {
        scoreList.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.scoreList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getItem(int index) {
        return this.scoreList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ItemViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_premier_rostatus, parent,false);
            viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder();
            viewHolder.name =  row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.score = row.findViewById(R.id.score);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        String[] stat = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.name.setText(stat[0]);
        viewHolder.score.setText(stat[1]);
        return row;
    }
}```


**CSVFile Class**

```public class CSVFile {
    InputStream inputStream;

    public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream){
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public List<String[]> read(){
        List<String[]> resultList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try {
            String csvLine;
            while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] row = csvLine.split(",");
                resultList.add(row);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file: "+ex);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error while closing input stream: "+e);
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}```

**activity_main.xml**



 ```android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_View"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"```
````

Comment: You need to implement any function in your adapter to accept the new `List<String>` with your modificated data and call to `notifyDataSetChanged` adapter function to repaint all the `ListView`.

Comment: Can you give me an example ? @SuperG280

Answer (score 0):

Based on your needs, you can use your existing adapter function `add` if you want to add only one item, or you can implement another adapter function to set all the List at a time.

When you need, you can execute this `add` or new function, with the new item or list, and then, you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

```
itemArrayAdapter.add( NewItem);
itemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or

```
itemArrayAdapter.addAllItemsInATime( NewArray);
itemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In this last case, you need to implement the new `addAllItemsInATime` (or the name you want) functions like this:

```
public void addAllItemsInATime( List<String> newList) {
    this.scoreList = newList;
}
```

Think about the Adapter class as an object that save the data and knows how this data will be showed. So, any data changed must be save in the adapter and repaint.